# Is there an easier way to iterate through a vector from the back?

Tags: c++, loops

So, normally I'd iterate this way:

```
for(int i{ n - 1 }; i >= 0; --i)
```

or like that:

```
for(size_t{v.size()-1}; i >= 0; --i)
    if(i > v.size()) break;
```

or that:

```
for(int* i{ &v.back() }; i >= &v.front(); --i)
```

But is there an easier/faster way to do that?

Here's the code, btw:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
vector<int> v(n);
for (auto& e : v)
    cin >> e;
int min = INT_MAX;
int count{};
for (int* i{ &v.back() }; i >= &v.front(); i--) {
    if (*i > min) count++;
        min = ::min(min, *i);
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/rbegin/

Answer (score 1):

From c++20, the easiest way to do this is with [`reverse_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) like this:

```
for (int i : std::ranges::reverse_view{v})
    // ...
```

which is as efficient as an index based loop or iterating from `rbegin` to `rend`.